# is there a way to calculate total earnings without repetition of amount from results

Tags: php, mysql

i have this code that calculate the total amount from a row. the solution adds up instead of printing only the expected results. for example 35,35 will give a result like 35,70 instead of printing only 70. the variable $stmt is associated to a query.

```
                                            <?php
                                            $netTotal = 0;

                                            foreach ($stmt as $val) {



                                            ?>

                                                <?php $t = $val['PAY_AMOUNT'] - (($val['PAY_AMOUNT']) * 0.1);
                                                $Total += $t;
                                                ?>
                                                <div class="col">
                                                    <h2 class="card-title font-size-40"><?php echo $Total; ?></h2>
                                                    <p class="card-sub font-size-18 line-height-24">Total Earnings</p>
                                                </div><?php } ?>
                                            <div class="col-auto font-size-60">
                                                <i class="la la-money text-primary"></i>
                                            </div>
                                        </div><!-- end row -->
                                    </div><!-- end card-content -->
```

Comment: you're outputting `$Total` (rather, the entire `<div class="col">...</div>`) inside of the `foreach` loop, so it's printing the total each iteration of the loop. You probably want to only calculate the total inside the foreach, and then output it once after the loop. i.e. `<?php foreach ($stmt as $val) { $Total += $t; } ?> <h2><?= $Total; ?></h2>`

Comment: When posting a question, please make sure that it has some sensible formatting (like removing excessive indentions etc)